# Error NU1202 Package Xamarin.Firebase.Database 60.1142.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, monodevelop

I am trying to develop a cross-platform IOS & Android app, is there a solution to this error?

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NU1202  Package Xamarin.Firebase.Database 60.1142.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Xamarin.Firebase.Database 60.1142.0 supports: monoandroid80 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)

Comment: Where are you adding the package? Also, is it a Xamarin.Forms project? And there is a newer version for Xamarin.Firebase.Database. Try to install the latest

Comment: That library is a native Android one. Firebase DB comes in Android, iOS and Javascript based libraries. These are all backed by a Rest API, there are un-official 3rd-party .Net wrappers for that Rest API that you could use from .NetStd, you lose some of the higher level features of those native libraries (like eventing, etc..) but you can always build those yourself.